# Block pointer variable 'block' is uninitialized when captured by block

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using the code seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8552184/1971013) to execute code periodically:

```
#define DELAY_IN_MS 1000
__block dispatch_time_t next = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0);
void (^block)(void) = ^  // Get warning here!
{
    next = dispatch_time(next, DELAY_IN_MS * 1000000L);

    // Do my periodic thing ...

    dispatch_after(next, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
}
```

This results in a warning (see title).  I have two questions about this warning:

- What does it mean?
- Why does the warning go away when I write: `void (^block)(void); block = ^`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To just declare your block you would use

```
void (^block)(void);
```

then initialize it with

```
block =^  // Get warning here!
{
    next = dispatch_time(next, DELAY_IN_MS * 1000000L);

    // Do my periodic thing ...

    dispatch_after(next, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
}
```

That is why putting in the semicolon works.

Why it gives you an error without the semicolon: you are referencing block in its own declaration/assignment. You are using it in the "dispatch_after" call, but its not fully set up yet.

Comment: Why isn't this the same as `int i = 0;` vs. `int i; i = 0;`.

Comment: Its more like int i = 3 + i;  vs int i; i = 3 + i;

Comment: I think I'm getting it.  So, `void (^block)(void);` sets up the block, as you call it?

Comment: Yes, its just like defining a variable initially.

Comment: Is this solution tested? As far as I see it, the captured `block` variable inside the block is `NULL` (the initial value from defining the variable) and I assume that `dispatch_after()` will crash. Using the `__block` modifier would help with that, but then you have a retain cycle. - See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18063382/1187415 for a possible solution.

Comment: A recursive block is fraught with danger. Yet the understanding of what causes the warning message was the meat and the crux of the question.

Comment: @MartinR Doesn't a defined variable contain stack/register shit, instead of `0`? It's not `static`.

Comment: @meaning-matters: With ARC, *Objective-C* objects are automatically initialized to nil. And blocks are also objects and managed by ARC.

Comment: What's the danger of the recursion here?  I've seen this suggested a few times, without these comments.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! Good to know! That's a detail I missed when switching to ARC.